# How to create timepicker dorp down with military time values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I'm trying to create dropdown that has option to pick the time from 7 am all the way up to 5pm with 15min increment. Before I explain my problem I want to let you know that I can not use JQuery in this case. I created Start time HTML:

```
<select name="stime" id="stime">
    <option value="">Pick the start time</option>
</select>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
  for(var i=0700; i<= 1700; i+=15){
    $('#stime').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+' </option>')
  }
});
```

This code give me weird numbers in my drop down. I would like ideally if I can have military time for my value in drop down, but to show in drop down time with columns like 7:00 or 14:00. If anyone can help me with this problem please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What weird numbers do you see? What numbers do you want?

Comment: Numbers like 448,463,478, 493,.... I want to get for values 0715,0730,0745 military time values, and display them like this 07:00, 07:15, 07:30. Reason why because I will have to add intervals on those values. If user pick start time 7:00 and pick interval 20min they will get option for the end time like 7:20, 7:40, 8:00, 8:20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not weird numbers, they are octal numbers. If you put a `0` as the first number you are telling that the number is an octal number, so the equivalent `for` with base 10 numbers would be

```
for(var i=448; i<= 1700; i+=15)
```

since `700` in octal is `448` in base 10.

Comment: I tried to put 448 for my i but still I have not get regular values with increment of 15min.

Comment: That is not what I meant. You need to put `700` and do some work around to create the select as you want. I made this example to show you one way to do it. https://jsfiddle.net/j3vdsu0s/

Comment: I looked at your example and works fine. I have question, so you did modulus to get min and then you added hour if min is greater than 45, and then you were multiplying by 100 why? And what slice do in the output? Thanks for your help one more time!

Comment: You're welcome ;) I multiplyed because the `hours` var has 2 digits and `i`, that has the military time, has 4 digits. I need slice because I added a `'0'` at the beginning of the hours (and mins) and we only need 2 digits (the 2 last).

Comment: That answered my question. How would be different if I want to keep military time for value as it it and display time to be standard am/pm?

Comment: Just get the modulus of the `hours`to no exceed 12 and check if hours is greater that 12, the it is `p.m.`, else is à.m.`. I have updated the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j3vdsu0s/1/

Comment: I did pretty similar with one exception in my case I was missing one 0 on the full hours. Other than that works fine. Thanks for help one more time!

Comment: And I think in your example your PM starts from 00 hours for some reason.

Comment: You just need this line of code: var standardHours = ((hours + 11) % 12) + 1; and replace standardHours instead of hours in the output.

Comment: Also for example 12:15 Should be PM. In your example is AM.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzhnyf1r/1/) Don't use '0700', use 700, and pad the output with 0's.

```
var t = 700,
    incr = 15;
while (t < 1700) {
  val = pad(t);
  // ...
  t += incr;
}
```

Comment: Still does not work correct for the full hour, instead of 9:00 am shows 0860.

Comment: Did you look at my example? It is working correctly there.

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle and there full hours are odd like I mentioned in comment above.

Comment: is this better? [https://jsfiddle.net/qzhnyf1r/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/qzhnyf1r/2/)

Comment: Yes that works perfect. I have one more question, if I have one more drop down where user can pick from 5min up to 60min. Should I be able to add those values to previously picked time with the same logic?